# Goland/Intellij - Change line background color based on text match

Tags: intellij-idea, themes, goland

I want to change the background color (shade it a bit dark) when a certain commonly occuring keyword (for example, logger or monitor) occurs in the line. The idea is to visually demarcate the code that's not relevant to the code logic.
Any idea how to do it in Goland or Intellij?

Preferences->Editor->color scheme has different configurations for various tokens and there's a way to change the background, but I can't find a regex or string search feature.

Comment: Does https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Yes it does. 
Added an item with regex `.*monitor.*` in Tools->Grep Console->Highlight Editor with grep console settings.
I can accept your answer.

Comment: Only problem is i don't know how to apply it automatically by default.